# Django CMS messages didn't pass with DEBUG false

Tags: django, django-cms

a have django-cms 3.1.2 and use such code to pass messages from one view to another

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Some text")
return redirect('/')
```

And it works fine when DEBUG=True and doesn't works at all when DEBUG=False - I don't receive any messages.

Comment: check for error log of your http server (in case of Apache/Ubuntu/Debian /var/log/apache2/error.log) , or try to run development server by "python manage.py runserver" and see log messages

Comment: there is no error message, it's just didn't work

Comment: ok, then provide your model/view/form to look at, i mean full text - it will help

Comment: Do see any error in your browser developer tools console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault :( Because instead of reverse to the view I just reverse to the direct URL, so any context wasn't passing to it.